# Why'd my Outlook 2016 display change?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

...and how do I change it back?

In both the preview and popped out view the attachment "bar" (between the simplified header info and the actual e-mail message) has changed.  Yesterday it would display all the attachments as small icons and would also include a "message" object pointing to the e-mail.  However, today, it suddenly displays larger attachment icons and the "message" object is missing.

Going around the office and checking with other people shows a fairly even mix.  About half have the display I have now and about half have the display I used to have.  We're all on Outlook 2016.  Appears that this is something that can be changed, but how?

Comment: Try toggling between Touch and Mouse mode. You can do this via the ribbon command.

Comment: Excellent thought, but that's not it.  Does not change that part of the display.

Comment: Crazy Outlook changed again on me.  Some of the icons from the main ribbon disappeared.  Finally noticed them chilling over on a new right side vertical ribbon thing I never used to have.  Argh, Why you so fickle Outlook?